# Battery information not displayed correctly on ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, laptop, power-management, battery

I did a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04.1 on an asus x556uak laptop and noticed that when connected to AC and the battery is not charging the system shows the battery icon as discharging , but when the battery has discharged a little and when connected again it charges, then system shows the battery icon as connected to AC and charging.

Also I've noticed that all though I have 2 38 Whr cells ubuntu is only detecting one 38 Whr cell, as if the second one doesn't exist? But maybe this is not a bug and it switches to secondary battery when the 1st one is empty?

This is the output of `upower -d`

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC0
  native-path:          AC0
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              IST 19:06:36 2017 ינו 07 ש' (1564 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              no
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               ASUSTeK
  model:                ASUS Battery
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              IST 19:32:37 2017 ינו 07 ש' (3 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              27.154 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         37.886 Wh
    energy-full-design:  38 Wh
    energy-rate:         8.648 W
    voltage:             7.6 V
    time to empty:       3.1 hours
    percentage:          72%
    capacity:            99.7%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (rate):
    1483810357  8.648   discharging

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              IST 19:32:37 2017 ינו 07 ש' (3 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  battery
    present:             yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              27.154 Wh
    energy-full:         37.886 Wh
    energy-rate:         8.648 W
    time to empty:       3.1 hours
    percentage:          72%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.4
  on-battery:      yes
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  critical-action: HybridSleep
```

I will update and post the output of `upower -d` when the battery is full and connected to AC.

Thank you for your time.

---

### UPDATE

This is the output of `upower -d` when the battery is allready charged and the laptop is plugged to AC:

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC0
  native-path:          AC0
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              IST 20:44:01 2017 ינו 07 ש' (21 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              yes
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               ASUSTeK
  model:                ASUS Battery
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              IST 20:44:01 2017 ינו 07 ש' (21 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              37.825 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         37.886 Wh
    energy-full-design:  38 Wh
    energy-rate:         3.564 W
    voltage:             7.6 V
    time to empty:       10.6 hours
    percentage:          100%
    capacity:            99.7%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1483814641  100.000 discharging
  History (rate):
    1483814641  3.564   discharging
    1483814641  2.348   discharging

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              IST 20:44:01 2017 ינו 07 ש' (21 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  battery
    present:             yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              37.825 Wh
    energy-full:         37.886 Wh
    energy-rate:         3.564 W
    time to empty:       10.6 hours
    percentage:          100%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.4
  on-battery:      no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  critical-action: HybridSleep
```